Screen flickering on MacBookPro
I've just installed Ubuntu (the latest 24.04.1 LTS) on my old MacBook Pro (Early 2015). Everything works perfectly at first, but after the device is left on it's own for a while, the power saving features (blank screen) activate and after resume the screen starts to flicker. The flickering is constant, the rate is fast and it's only barely visible, but quite disturbing nonetheless.
The device is plugged in power and the battery is fully charged.
I've tried disabling power saving features

automatic screen brightness : off
dim screen : off
automatic suspend : when on battery power

I've tried changing display settings, resolution and scaling.
I've tried restarting the device, turning power off/on, but the problem remains.
After leaving the device powered off overnight, everything was good again for a while. What's really odd is that while i'm writing this, the flickering seems to slowly diminish. It's like there's some kind of phase/rate problem, where two oscillators start out of phase with each other after resuming from blank screen. So my guess is that it has something to do with the various sync clocks and settings of the display.
Disabling the blank screen feature removes the problem, but that's not ideal. I've looked into system log and whatever comes up with journalctl | grep -i 'wayland.*]: ', but didn't recognize any obvious error. My system doesn't have X11 logs and i don't know where to look for more information.
System specs:

MacBookPro 12,1
Intel Iris Graphics 6100 (BDW GT3)
Linux 6.8.0-45-generic

Last time i managed and maintained a linux pc was some decade ago and i'm positively surprised how well Ubuntu supports out-of-the-box this old macbook.
